# How to grep for contents after pattern?

Tags: linux, grep

Given a file, for example:

```
potato: 1234
apple: 5678
potato: 5432
grape: 4567
banana: 5432
sushi: 56789
```

I'd like to grep for all lines that start with `potato:` but only pipe the numbers that follow `potato:`.  So in the above example, the output would be:

```
1234
5432
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
grep 'potato:' file.txt | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

[`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) looks for any line that contains the string `potato:`, then, for each of these lines, [`sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) replaces (`s///` - substitute) any character (`.*`) from the beginning of the line (`^`) until the last occurrence of the sequence `:` (colon followed by space) with the empty string (`s/...//` - substitute the first part with the second part, which is empty).

or

```
grep 'potato:' file.txt | cut -d\   -f2
```

For each line that contains `potato:`, [`cut`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html) will split the line into multiple fields delimited by space (`-d\` - `d` = delimiter, `\` = escaped space character, something like `-d" "` would have also worked) and print the second field of each such line (`-f2`).

or

```
grep 'potato:' file.txt | awk '{print $2}'
```

For each line that contains `potato:`, [`awk`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) will print the second field (`print $2`) which is delimited by default by spaces.

or

```
grep 'potato:' file.txt | perl -e 'for(<>){s/^.*: //;print}'
```

All lines that contain `potato:` are sent to an inline (`-e`) [Perl](https://perldoc.perl.org) script that takes all lines from [`stdin`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)), then, for each of these lines, does the same substitution as in the first example above, then prints it.

or

```
awk '{if(/potato:/) print $2}' < file.txt
```

The file is sent via `stdin` (`< file.txt` sends the contents of the file via `stdin` to the command on the left) to an `awk` script that, for each line that contains `potato:` (`if(/potato:/)` returns true if the regular expression `/potato:/` matches the current line), prints the second field, as described above.

or

```
perl -e 'for(<>){/potato:/ && s/^.*: // && print}' < file.txt
```

The file is sent via `stdin` (`< file.txt`, see above) to a Perl script that works similarly to the one above, but this time it also makes sure each line contains the string `potato:` (`/potato:/` is a regular expression that matches if the current line contains `potato:`, and, if it does (`&&`), then proceeds to apply the regular expression described above and prints the result).

Comment: No need for two processes and a pipe.
I would go for `awk '$1 ~ /potato/ { print $2 }' file.txt`.

Comment: The awk one would more idiomatically be `awk '/potato:/ {print $2}'`

Comment: The Perl scripts could benefit from `perl -pe`

Comment: See also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 90):

Or use regex assertions: `grep -oP '(?<=potato: ).*' file.txt`

Comment: I tried some one-liners from the accepted answer above, but I feel that this answer more accurately solves the question.

Comment: Some explanation: Option `-o` means print only the matching part of the line. Whereas `-P` infers a Perl-compatible regular expression, which happens to be a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regex `(?<=string)`.

Comment: **Note**: because of the `-P` option, this solution is only compatible with [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/), it won't work with the kind of [POSIX `grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) you can find in environments such as macOS.

Comment: @rid that is a good point. One can download `GNU grep` on macOS with `brew install grep` and use it as `ggrep`, i.e., with an extra `g` prefix.

Answer (score 26):

```
grep -Po 'potato:\s\K.*' file
```

`-P` to use Perl regular expression

`-o` to output only the match

`\s` to match the space after `potato:`

`\K` to omit the match

`.*` to match rest of the string(s)

Comment: Thanks for regex explanation.

Comment: **Note**: because of the `-P` option, this solution is only compatible with [GNU `grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/), it won't work with the kind of [POSIX `grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) you can find in environments such as macOS.

Answer (score 14):

```
sed -n 's/^potato:[[:space:]]*//p' file.txt
```

One can think of Grep as a restricted Sed, or of Sed as a generalized Grep.  In this case, Sed is one good, lightweight tool that does what you want -- though, of course, there exist several other reasonable ways to do it, too.

Answer (score 2):

This will print everything after each match, on that same line only:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /^potato:\s*(.*)/' file.txt
```

This will do the same, except it will also print all subsequent lines:

```
perl -lne 'if ($found){print} elsif (/^potato:\s*(.*)/){print $1; $found++}' file.txt
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around each line of the input file
- `-l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `-e` execute the perl code

Answer (score 2):

You can use grep, as the other answers state. But you don't need grep, awk, sed, perl, cut, or any external tool. You can do it with pure bash.

Try this (semicolons are there to allow you to put it all on one line):

```
$ while read line;
  do
    if [[ "${line%%:\ *}" == "potato" ]];
    then
      echo ${line##*:\ };
    fi;
  done< file.txt
```

## tells bash to delete the longest match of ": " in $line from the front.

```
$ while read line; do echo ${line##*:\ }; done< file.txt
1234
5678
5432
4567
5432
56789
```

or if you wanted the key rather than the value, %% tells bash to delete the longest match of ": " in $line from the end.

```
$ while read line; do echo ${line%%:\ *}; done< file.txt
potato
apple
potato
grape
banana
sushi
```

The substring to split on is ":\ " because the space character must be escaped with the backslash.

You can find more like these at [the linux documentation project](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Comment: `while read` is extremely slow; using an external utility will actually be much faster as long as you choose one with buffered I/O (i.e. practically any of the ones mentioned in this answer, and many others).

Comment: Also, you should use `read -r` unless you are very specifically requiring some rather pesky legacy behavior from before POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Modern BASH has support for regular expressions:

```sh
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ ^potato:\ ([0-9]+) ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: You want to avoid this, though. [Bash `while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why)

Comment: @tripleee How to replace "while read" with "cat"? It does not make much sense to compare those two. This means in the end: do not use Bash at all, because using CPU registers directly is much faster.

Comment: The gist of the linked question is to use Awk or `sed` or `grep` etc to loop over all the lines in the file when you can. `cat` alone is not an improvement at all (its purpose is to concatenate multiple files; if you use it on a single file, you are [doing it wrong);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) it's just a benchmark for comparison. If you are looping over one line at a time anyway for other reasons, this is still a viable technique (like, say you are extracting the name of a file which you then process inside the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use rg:

```
$ rg -N --trim potato: -r '' file.txt
1234
5432
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-N` suppress line numbers
- `--trim` trim all ASCII whitespace at the beginning of each line
- `-r ''` remove matched pattern, in this case 'potato:'

Answer (score -3):

```
grep potato file | grep -o "[0-9].*"
```