# Extracting string after matched pattern in Shell

Tags: regex, shell

How to extract whatever string comes after a matched pattern in Shell script. I know this functionality in Perl scripting, but i dont know in Shell scripting.

Following is the example,

> Subject_01: This is a sample subject and this may vary

I have to extract whatever string that follows "Subject_01:"

Any help please.

Comment: What shell are you using?  Bourne?  CSH?  KSH88?  [RC](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/rc.html)?

Comment: For extracting from a file, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/how-to-grep-for-contents-after-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your shell.

If you're using [bourne](/questions/tagged/bourne) shell or [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) or (I believe) [pdksh](/questions/tagged/pdksh), then you can do fancy stuff like this:

```
$ string="Subject_01: This is a sample subject and this may vary"
$ output="${string#*: }"
$ echo $output
This is a sample subject and this may vary
$
```

Note that this is pretty limited in terms of format. The line above requires that you have ONE space after your colon.  If you have more, it will pad the beginning of `$output`.

If you're using some other shell, you may have to do something like this, with the `cut` command:

```
> setenv string "Subject_01: This is a sample subject and this may vary"
> setenv output "`echo '$string' | cut -d: -f2`"
> echo $output
This is a sample subject and this may vary
> setenv output "`echo '$string' | sed 's/^[^:]*: *//'`"
> echo $output
This is a sample subject and this may vary
>
```

The first example uses `cut`, which is very small and simple.  The second example uses `sed`, which can do far more, but is a (very) little heavier in terms of CPU.

YMMV.  There's probably a better way to handle this in csh (my second example uses tcsh), but I do most of my shell programming in Bourne.

Comment: For cut, if you just want to drop the first field (in case there are colons in the rest of the string), use `-f2-`

Comment: @glennjackman - true, thanks for pointing that out.  That notation will return the rest of the line, even including whitespace around subsequent colons, though it still doesn't let us trim the whitespace at the start.