# Grep digits after match

Tags: grep

I would like to grep digits inside a set of parentheses after a match.

Given `foo.txt` below,

```
foo: "32.1" bar: "42.0" misc: "52.3"
```

I want to extract the number after bar, `42.0`.

The following line will match, but I'd like to extract the digit. I guess I could pipe the output back into grep looking for `\d+.\d+`, but is there a better way?

```
grep -o -P 'bar: "\d+.\d+"' foo.txt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grep for contents after pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/how-to-grep-for-contents-after-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use look ahead and look-behind assertions:

```
grep -o -P '(?<=bar: ")\d+.\d+(?=")'
```

Another is to use sed:

```
sed -e 's/.*bar: "\([[:digit:]]\+.[[:digit:]]\+\)".*/\1/'
```

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about those. :-)

More info on look-ahead and look-behind assertions in Perl can be found here: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below grep also,

```
$ echo 'foo: "32.1" bar: "42.0" misc: "52.3"' | grep -oP 'bar:\s+"\K[^"]*(?=")'
42.0
```