# Import PATH environment variable into Bash script launched with cron

Tags: linux, bash, path, cron

When creating Bash scripts, I have always had a line right at the start defining the `PATH` environment variable. I recently discovered that this doesn't make the script very portable as the `PATH` variable is different for different versions of Linux (in my case, I moved the script from Arch Linux to Ubuntu and received errors as various executables weren't in the same places).

Is it possible to copy the `PATH` environment variable defined by the login shell into the current Bash script?

---

**EDIT:**
I see that my question has caused some confusion resulting in some thinking that I want to change the `PATH` environment variable of the login shell with a bash script, which is the exact opposite of what I want.

This is what I currently have at the top of one of my Bash scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
# Test if an internet connection is present
wget -O /dev/null google.com
```

I want to replace that second line with something that **copies** the value of `PATH` **from** the login shell **into** the script environment:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$(command that copies value of PATH from login shell)
# Test if an internet connection is present
wget -O /dev/null google.com
```

---

**EDIT 2**: Sorry for the big omission on my part. I forgot to mention that the scripts in question are being run on a schedule through cron. Cron creates it's own environment for running the scripts which does not use the environment variables of the login shell or modify them. I just tried running the following script in cron:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $PATH >> /home/user/output.txt
```

The result is as follows. As you can see, the `PATH` variable used by cron is different to the login shell:

```
user@ubuntu_router:~$ cat output.txt
/usr/bin:/bin
user@ubuntu_router:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Comment: why do you want to do this ?

Comment: On Mac OS X, the `/etc/profile` contains: `if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`; fi`.  This sets `PATH` and `MANPATH`.  You can find questions about `path_helper` on U&L and SU — the speed issue mentioned has been resolved (a few — as in 8-10 — milliseconds on 10.11.6).  Look in `/etc/paths.d` perhaps on Linux?  But the question stands — why do you want to tinker with the PATH? I might have my own views about which versions of the commands should be used; that's what my PATH settings are for. Of course, if I break your script, the onus is on me to fix it.

Comment: I'm afraid the two of you have misunderstood what I was requesting. I have edited my question to hopefully clear things up.

Comment: No, you are not understanding what these comments are telling you. What you are asking for is poor behavior on the part of your program, and seems to be based on a false assumption.

Comment: *All* processes inherit a value for `PATH` from their parents. You don't have to do anything special. If you need proof, put `echo $PATH` as the very first line of your script.

Comment: I have edited my question again. I just realized that there was a very important piece of information that I forgot to mention. I'm terribly sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find the answer to my question:

```
PATH=$PATH:$(sed -n '/PATH=/s/^.*=// ; s/\"//gp' '/etc/environment')
```

This command will grab the value assigned to `PATH` by Linux from the `environment` file and append it to the `PATH` used by Cron.

I used the following resources to help find the answer:

[How to grep for contents after pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/grep-for-contents-after-pattern)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables

Answer (score 5):

Don't touch the user's `PATH` at all unless you have a specific reason. Not doing anything will (basically) accomplish what you ask.

You don't have to do anything to get the user's normal `PATH` since every process inherits the `PATH` and all other environment variables automatically.

If you need to add something nonstandard to the `PATH`, the usual approach is to prepend (or append) the new directory to the user's existing `PATH`, like so:

```
PATH=/opt/your/random/dir:$PATH
```

The environment of `cron` jobs is pretty close to the system's "default" (for some definition of "default") though interactive shells may generally run with a less constrained environment. But again, the fix for that is to add any missing directories to the current value at the beginning of the script. Adding directories which don't exist on this particular system is harmless, as is introducing duplicate directories.

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. I don't want to modify the `PATH` environment variable. I want to copy the value of that environment variable into the script's environment.

Comment: I believe I understand you perfectly;  if you do nothing, you will inherit the user's `PATH`, which in most cases will be identical to the system's default `PATH`, and if it isn't, the user most likely has a good reason to have configured it that way. Anyway, it's not necessary for there to be a single system-wide default, though it's common practice e.g. on Linux. If you do feel the need to override the user's configured preference, the mechanism I describe is what you should probably do instead of what you seem to want.

Comment: I have edited my question again. I just realized that there was a very important piece of information that I forgot to mention. I'm terribly sorry.

Comment: I basically still stand by this answer, though I updated it briefly with some `cron` remarks.