# Grep/Awk: Find status from table column

Tags: awk, docker, grep, dokku

`dokku ls` shows the following but how can I get the status of `app-1470418443` using `awk` for example ?

So that `magic command` returns `running`.

```
-----> App Name           Container Type            Container Id              Status                   
app-1470418443            web                       78a092d176f1              running                  
example                   web                       3b7803c49e04              running                  
example2                  web                       a750f2b4be44              running
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep for contents AFTER pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/grep-for-contents-after-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '$1=="app-1470418443"{print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is trailing space in the example output you have to get all non-space characters (`[^ ]*`) and then all the space (`_*`, *underscore _ represents space as space didn't render at all*) in the end of the string (`$`) and print only the matching parts (`grep -o`):

```
$ grep "^app-1470418443 " file | grep -o "[^ ]* *$"
running
```

Without trailing space, the latter `grep` would simplify a bit (well 2 bytes) to match only the non-space chars:

```
$ grep "^app-1470418443 " file | grep -o "[^ ]*$"
running
```