# In linux system, how to find the words (immediately next alone) next to a given word in a file?

Tags: linux, file, unix

I need to find all the table names alone in all select statements in my query log. Is there any way to `grep` (or) any other option, to take the strings that comes immediately after the word `FROM` in my file ..

Example: `file` contains something like this

```
select a, b, c FROM `table1` join `table2` etc...
insert into.................
commit
select * FROM `tablex` ..............
select y,s,h FROM `tabley`.................
.
.
.
```

Now I want the list of the distinct tables alone from the select stmts. i.e,

```
table1
tablex
tabley
```

Comment: Give a minimal sample input and expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep for contents AFTER pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/grep-for-contents-after-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but if you want to extract the first word that comes after 'from' you can try something like this:

```
➜  tmp cat log 
select id, name from account where name = 'John';
select * from price where id > 0;
➜  tmp cat log | gawk -F'from ' '{print $2}' | gawk '{print $1}'
account
price
➜  tmp
```

If you want to print names of joined tables as well you need to extend it.

Comment: thank u  @g-t :yes this is partly working fine. can i have this input in a file? since the count is high i dont get to c all the tables.. and yeah how to extend for the joined tables as well??