# SH grep output only certain string

Tags: grep, sh

Im trying to get a certain part of my output from grep. Currently I get the full text that could look like: "Location: /path/to/file" or "State: Error". However I want to only print the second part that is "/path/to/file" and "Error". Observe that one output contains "`Elapsed time: 568 hours (23.6 days)`" and I need to remove the `hours (23.6 days)` part. These are all different grep and unique code can be used for each one.

So what I expect as a result is to give the input:

```
Elapsed time:    568 hours (23.6 days)
```

and the output should be `568`

For the other example I expect as a result is to give the input:

```
State:    Error
```

And the output should be `Error`

I tried to check up something called awk and sed, got a little confused and not very clear how to implement it on my problem.

```
`grep "Elapsed Time: *" | sed -e 's/Elapsed Time://g'`
```

this would print out 568  hours (23.6 days).

```
 grep "Location: *" | sed -e 's/Location://g'
```

works but contains a lot of empty space between Location: and /path/to/file, can the spaces be removed in one go aswell?

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you, added some text on what the exact input is and what output I want to achieve, about links I dont really have any good references

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to grep for contents after pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/how-to-grep-for-contents-after-pattern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If row contains `Elapsed time:` print third column:

```
echo 'Elapsed time:    568 hours (23.6 days)' | awk '/Elapsed time:/{print $3}'
```

or with GNU grep and Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE)

```
echo 'Elapsed time:    568 hours (23.6 days)' | grep -Po 'Elapsed time: *\K.*(?= hours)'
```

or with GNU sed and extended regex:

```
echo 'Elapsed time:    568 hours (23.6 days)' | sed -r 's/Elapsed time: *(.*) hours.*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
568
```