# Bash Cut text before and after id

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have line:

```
<doc lang="en" func="auth" binary="/dnsmgr" host="https://dns.test.com" theme="orion" stylesheet="login" features="b993e382360bcbb508601df300594747" notify=""><auth id="4b0b5cb2210b" level="16">4b0b5cb2210b</auth><tparams><out>xml</out><username>user191642</username><func>auth</func></tparams></doc>
```

I need to extract id from `<auth id="4b0b5cb2210b"`
So my result must be: `4b0b5cb2210b`

This is a result of the curl requests, so ID will be different next time. Please help me get only the id.

I have tried this to cut the line:

```
awk -F'level' '{print $1}' | sed 's/^\s*auth id=//' | grep 'auth id=' | sed 's/^.*: //'
```

and got:

```
<doc lang=en func=auth binary=/dnsmgr host=https://dns.test.com theme=orion stylesheet=login features=b993e382360bcbb508601df300594747 notify=><auth id=4b0b5cb2210b
```

I'm close enough to the result. Please help me cut the text before the exact id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to grep for contents after pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358547/how-to-grep-for-contents-after-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU grep`

```
$ grep -oP '<auth id="\K[^"]+(?=")' ip.txt
4b0b5cb2210b
```

- `<auth id="\K` match `<auth id="` but don't use it for output
- `[^"]+` non `"` characters
- `(?=")` to make sure there is `"` after the auth id value

With `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/.*<auth id="([^"]+)/\1/' ip.txt
4b0b5cb2210b
```

- `.*<auth id="` match from start of line till `<auth id="`
- `([^"]+)` capture auth id value
- `".*` rest of the line
- `\1` use the captured text as replacement string

---

What went wrong with OP's attempt:

```
$ awk -F'level' '{print $1}' ip.txt 
<doc lang="en" func="auth" binary="/dnsmgr" host="https://dns.test.com" theme="orion" stylesheet="login" features="b993e382360bcbb508601df300594747" notify=""><auth id="4b0b5cb2210b"
```

The above command gives text before `level`. Piping it to `sed 's/^\s*auth id=//'` will not work because `^` anchors the match to start of line. Whereas the line starts with `<doc`. Changing `^\s*` to `.*` will give:

```
$ awk -F'level' '{print $1}' ip.txt | sed 's/.*auth id=//'
"4b0b5cb2210b"
```

The `.` metacharacter matches any character. So, everything until `auth id=` will be now be removed. The quotes can then be deleted using another substitution.

```
$ awk -F'level' '{print $1}' ip.txt | sed 's/.*auth id=//; s/"//g'
4b0b5cb2210b
```

This is for explanation purpose only, simpler solution is at the start of the answer.