# How do I grep something and prevent the phrase appearing in the results?

Tags: regex, linux, grep, pcre

How do I grep something and prevent the phrase appearing in the results?

I am trying to get only the MAC address from multiple systems and want only the MAC address in the results.

```sh
ipmitool lan print | grep "MAC Address             : "
# => MAC Address             : aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

I got as far using google as trying is by adding `-oP` and `\K\w+` but for some reason it only get's the first 2 digits of the MAC:

```sh
ipmitool lan print | grep -oP "MAC Address             : \K\w+"
# => aa
```

I understand the `-o` will only show the matched text which is why the MAC address is not being shown up and `-P` used with `\K` will prevent everything in-between from showing up but not sure what exactly to put after `\w+` to make the rest of the MAC address show up.

Comment: Try `grep -oP "MAC Address : \K\S+"`

Comment: Thank you so much! That got it~

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew can you post it as a answer so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Albeit https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840426/11329890  looks like an answer, its `.*` can go much farther than a single word, and MAC address is a single word. This post looks useful, with a better explanation of the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match it with

```
grep -oP 'MAC Address : \K\S+' file
```

Here,

- `-o` - extracts the matched texts, not whole lines
- `P` - enables the PCRE regex syntax
- `MAC Address :`  - matches a literal text
- `\K`  - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the memory match buffer
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars.

Comment: `grep -P` is not portable, though. The traditional solution would be `sed -n 's/.*MAC Address : //p'` or perhaps `sed -n 's/.*MAC Address : \([0-9a-fA-F:]*\).*/\1/p'` if there may be text after the match which should not be printed.

Comment: @tripleee That is all good, just note the answer is meant to address the immediate issue without forcing OP to change the tool set used. I myself do not need any alternative if I am used to a specific tool. In this case, I'd also use `grep` with `-P` since I am a regular Ubuntu Linux user and an NFA regex fan. If OP were interested in `sed` solution, I'd have added it to the answer.

Comment: Sure, just commenting for future visitors. Perhaps this should be closed as a duplicate of an existing question anyhow, where then hopefully portability of answers would be at least broadly documented.